# Как отслеживать время в девайсе?

Tags: android

Ситуация: Я хочу создать приложение которое показывает текущее время и  некую дату(это не текущая дата,а прошлая дата). Проще говоря,это простой app который должен показывать текущее время,но в прошлой дате.
Пример: 29.10.1986   23:28:32

Что я сделал? 
Сперва хотел вывести текущее время. Для этого нашел `TextClock`. Но увидел,что это простой статический label,за которым нельзя отслеживать программно. 
Как вы заметили,дата должна быть пройденной. Значит мне нужен какой-то clock, и когда он дойдет до 23:59:59, я должен обновить дату. Другого решения я не вижу.

Вопрос: 
Как нужно решать проблему? Что мне следует использовать? Timer,TimerTask? Нужен ли Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что должно произойти после 23:59:59? 
какой должна стать дата 30.10.1986 или остатся прежней 29.10.1986?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(1986, 9, 29);
```

каждую секунду добавлять по одной секунде к календарю

```
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm"); // формат выберете такой как вам нужно.
String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

p.s. если дата не будет менятся, то строку нужно создавать из двух частей дата + форматированое время, а если будет то просто нужно форматировать время

Comment: Дата должна стать 30.10.1986. Кстати, что делать если SimpleDateFormat не для всех версий Android работает?

Comment: тогда использовать старый-добрый способ))
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTHS) + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOURS) и так далее

Comment: Какой это способ? Можете подробнее

Comment: поправил свой ответ

Comment: (последний вопрос,надеюсь) Как мерить секунду? Какой метод использовать,чтобы он каждую секунду добавлял?

Comment: не смог сюда написать код, то добавил новый ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61807/discussion-between-andy11-and-andriy-martsinkevych).

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int TIME_OUT = 1000;
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // магия здесь))
                    }
                });
            }
        }, TIME_OUT, TIME_OUT);
```

Comment: Допустим сейчас время `22:25:00` , а дата `29.10.1986` . Например,когда я открою приложение через час и 35 минут, дата уже должна быть `30.10.1986`. Вопрос: как мне написать чтобы он именно определенное количество секунд добавлял? Надеюсь поняли))